# Based on Data Augmentation in numerical dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-augmentation

I want to develop a machine learning model for a dataset like 5 inputs and 1 output. I stuck in stage with not sufficient dataset, I am aware about data augmentation technique in image and text type data's is there any specific method for numerical data like this. If there is any technique pls help to resolve the problem also if possible cite some reference with example code.

Comment: Data augmentation is usually useful to model some type of invariance in your data; i.e. given data point X with label Y, imagine a new 'version'/transformation of X called X'. If you can reasonably assume that X' still has label Y, or whatever info you care about for the task, it's probably a valid augmentation. Could you give a concrete example of what the input/output looks like for your task?

Comment: for me inputs like continuous numerical data inputs I want apply data augmentation in this  type of data type